# Number Duplicated Cases

Tags: r, duplicates

I want to identify duplicate cases and number them as a vector (such as with an ID variable). Any case without any direct matches should be labeled as a fixed value (such as zero). Any case with a corresponding duplicate should be labeled 1, with each subsequent case being labeled n+1. So, if I have an ID variable like this 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, I'd want the corresponding vector to produce: 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0.

How can I do this?

Duplicate identifies the first case as a non-duplicate, so that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R, `ave` with `seq_along`

```
x<-c(1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5)
ave(seq_along(x),x,FUN=function(g) if(length(g)>1) seq_along(g) else 0)
#>   0 1 2 3 0 1 2 0
```

Comment: That is it! I'm incredibly impressed at how  quickly these responses came. Thank you very much for this!

Comment: Any thoughts on applying this to a string variable (i.e. factor)? I just tried running it using a factor and received numerous error messages with lots of NA's

Comment: See edit. It is using the attributes of the first argument, which in the case of a factor may not have levels corresponding to the zeros or counts. Any dummy vector of the correct length and desired attributes would work in this case.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. This is tremendously useful